# Can metal drink cans be melted at home?

Tags: recycling, reuse

Can metal drink cans be melted at home and reused, remoulded into something?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! To prevent spam and misuse this site works with [reputation points](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) which you can earn when you ask good questions or write good answers. Once you have 15 points you can show your appreciation for other posts by upvoting. Meanwhile I took the liberty to revise your question post because that should focus on the question you have.

Comment: I found a rather similar question [here](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/7199/99). Do the answers there help you? If not, can you please edit your question and add how your question is different?

Comment: no thats brill ... thanks .... on the right track sort of 

but could you add my thanks under neath my question ?

Comment: I can't post comments for you, but you can write them under your own posts yourself. Also you now have enough reputation to upvote and thank people for good questions or answers that way.

Comment: terrific - thank you

Comment: Oh and thanks for welcoming me and welcome :)